# Is there away to speed up this code even more?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to speed up this code even more? I have applied all the techniques I found on using arrays and avoiding using selects but it is not fast enough.

Maybe there is something I could tweak or change and I didn't realize

Thank you

```
Sub Operation()

Dim t As Long
Dim valor As Double
Dim arr As Variant

arr = Empty

valor = Worksheets("Datos").Range("E24").Value


arr = Hoja5.Cells(valor, "A").CurrentRegion

For t = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)

    
    Hoja7.Range("A9:IL9") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, t, 0)
    arr(t, UBound(arr, 2)) = Hoja7.Cells(30, 2)
    Application.StatusBar = "Simulación Nro " & t
    
Next t

Hoja5.Range("IP51").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, UBound(arr, 2))


Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Exclude the `Application.StatusBar` parts of the code.

Comment: Another thought: run it on a clean Excel session without further AddIns that may be commonly running. Open Excel this way (Win+R then type Excel /s)

Comment: Is Hoja7.Cells(30, 2) a constant value? Then make it a separate variable. Consider a Foreach loop instead. ALeXcel's comment about removing the Application.StatusBar line. In general, each dot operation adds time and overhead.

Comment: How can I use a FOR EACH instead a FOR in an array? Thx

Comment: What happens between assigning the array "row" to the worksheet and reading the value from B30?  Do you have calculations on the sheet?  If Yes how complex are they and how much do they contribute to your run time?  This code seems fine to me - likely the slowness is on the worksheet.

Comment: FYI using Index to "slice" an array is >10x slower than looping and filling a second array, but in the scheme of things that may not matter here.

Comment: yes, i have lots of calculations on Hoja7. Probably it is that. But I will definetely take into account about looping than slicing with index. Thx Tim

Comment: If you set calculation to manual and run that code you'll get some idea of how much the calculation contributes to the total run time.